Do people get points when I vote up their comments?
I always take time to vote up comments that I think are particularly contributing. Am I just wasting my time?

On a related note, make sure to not upvote comments that do not follow their intended purpose

See the section titled "How do I earn reputation," especially the sub-section starting with "You gain reputation when" at this help page: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation

Whether you are wasting your time depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  Your upvotes on comments help others recognize  those comments as more likely to be valuable and therefore more worth reading.  That's a valuable service (to others) if you're upvoting wisely.

Comment votes do not earn any reputation. However, when the comment thread grows past a certain length and becomes truncated (i.e. when you have to click the "Show X more comments" button to see all of them), the ones with more votes are prioritized in the initial truncated view.

They can earn you badges, though!
